# Why is NoActionbar Theme affecting ScrollView & overall Layout?

Tags: android, layout, themes, android-actionbar, scrollview

So i have a layout in Android where its a vertical LinearLayout that encompasses A ScrollView, LinearLayout, LinearLayout.

I made each child take about roughly a 3rd of the screen. When I have them **Holo** or **Holo.Light** with an ActionBar is looks as expected:

[image: image1]

However, when I change the Theme to Holo.NoActionBar or Holo.Light.NoActionBar, for some reason, it completely ignores my android:layout_weight, or even my ScrollView. Like all my contents in my scroll view are no longer collapsed.
It then looks like this:

[image: image2]

Why does this happen? I cannont figure out why. I even made a custom theme in my styles.xml and the problem still existed. **How come ScrollView only works when I have an ActionBar?**

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
     >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

                       .......................

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="40">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSendEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/sendEmail" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="30">


        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```